# Angular binding on dynamic (deep-)property

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, lodash

I'm trying to build an Angular-app where an object is generated at runtime. The structure of that object is complete unknown, it can get any type of properties, even nested ones. Now I want Angular to use its binding-mechanism on an specific (nested) property on that object.

Let's say the object is:

```
const dynamicObject={
  propA: 7,
  propB: 3,
  propC: {
    propD: 5,
    propE: 1
  }
}
```

and I want to use "propC.propD" for binding in HTML:

```
<input matInput [value]="dynamicObject.propC.propD">
```

Now I want to change that binded prop on runtime, let's say to "propA". Therefore I'm using the lodash-"get()"-function (https://lodash.com/docs/#get).

Typescript:

```
const actPath='propA';
```

HTML:

```
<input matInput [value]="_.get(dynamicObject, actPath)">
```

Which works, angular only triggers the change in that component when the value of propA changes. Problem here is that the get()-method is called the whole time, which is wasted performance.

What also works is using square brackets ("[]") to get the property dynamic:

```
<input matInput [value]="dynamicObject[actPath]">
```

But this isn't working for nested props like dynamicObject['propC.propD']. Maybe there is a way to compile the component later with the correct inserted path (componentFactory, etc.)?

This is a simplified example of what I'm doing, so here it maybe seems a bit overcomplicate. 
Someone got an idea how to achive what I need? Thanks!

Comment: What if you try to reflect that change through a property, that is, you bind your `matInput`'s value to a property `get_value` and in `get_value` you do the logic for querying `dynamicObject`.

Comment: I don't understand your statement "get()-method is called the whole time, which is wasted performance". Yes, the method will be evaluated on every change detection - but so are the "simple" bindings. Is there a specific performance issue you're seeing? If not, then I think you might be worrying over nothing - an extra stack frame isn't going to matter much

Comment: Also, you could always do it the "old fashioned" way - bind to a single property on the component and just change that field whenever `dynamicObject` or `actPath` change. It's a PIA because it introduces the opportunity for the component property to get "out of sync", but that's a reasonable trade-off for performance

Comment: @Vlad274 In my case I use this inside an custom datagrid, where this is used in every cell. So that get-function is called really often.

Comment: You can use object in object property like this. ```interface Prop {propName: string; propVal: string}``` . In angular view you must use setter dynamicObject.prop(PropName, PropValue).